# php map_fetch_overview() returns incomplete headers

Tags: php, imap

I'm using `imap_fetch_overview()` to retrieve mail headers and I'm facing the following issue -

Consider four users - A1, B1, C1, D1

A1 sends a email message to B1, C1, D1.

When D1 opens his mailbox, and goes and clicks on a particular message, I go to fetch the headers for that message. The `To` header attribute should have `B1`,`C1`,`D1`'s mail address.

But `imap_fetch_overview()` returns only the first email address ie - `B1`.

Is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: Can you post the code? Can you also FETCH the email manually with IMAP (e.g. using telnet, or my IMAPTalk client) and see whether the header is correct?

Comment: @Gigi, the telnet client returns the correct headers.